# Differences between M_CACHE, M_DEVBUF, M_TEMP

Tags: c, memory-management, kernel, malloc, freebsd

I am trying to understand the difference in these three different memories.
Code comments in kern_malloc.c

```
/*
 * Centrally define some common malloc types.
 */
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_CACHE, "cache", "Various Dynamically allocated caches");
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_DEVBUF, "devbuf", "device driver memory");
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_TEMP, "temp", "misc temporary data buffers");
```

What can be the major difference between the three memories in terms of allocation and deallocation and management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MALLOC_DECLARE` and `MALLOC_DEFINE` macros are used to create `malloc_type` structures. These `malloc_type` structures are passed to the various kernel-level memory management functions for the purpose of gathering useful statistics about how the kernel memory is being used.

For example, when you use `malloc(sizeof(my_type), M_DEVBUF, M_WAITOK)` to allocate some memory, you can see information about this and all other allocations which pass along the `M_DEVBUF` type using `vmstat -m`. On my system:

```sh
$ vmstat -m | head -n 1 && vmstat -m | grep "devbuf"

  Type InUse MemUse HighUse Requests  Size(s)
devbuf 16806 34311K       -    16837  16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,32768,65536
```

You can make your own `malloc_type`s to track your own kernel level allocations.

```c
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_MYDRIVER, "mydriver", "buffers used by my driver");

void d_foo() {
  void * x = malloc(sizeof(foo), M_MYDRIVER, M_WAITOK);
}
```

```sh
$ vmstat -m | head -n 1 && vmstat -m | grep "mydriver"
    Type InUse MemUse HighUse Requests  Size(s)
mydriver     1     4K       -        1
```

The man page for the kernel memory management functions is accessible via `$ man 9 malloc`.